# Efficient computation of density of ratio of two normal random variables

Tags: numerical-integration, probability-or-statistics, special-functions, distributions

I want to manipulate the density of the ratio of two normal random variables. One way to do this is:

```
 TransformedDistribution[c/b, {c, b} \[Distributed]
                         BinormalDistribution[{µs, µb}, {sc,sb}, Rho]]
```

Computationally, this is obviously very demanding. But there are exact closed-form expressions in terms of Hermite and confluent hypergeometric functions (see e.g. [this paper](http://www.tandfonline.com/doi/abs/10.1080/03610920600683689)). Has anyone implemented these in Mathematica?

Comment: Have you seen the result of `PDF[TransformedDistribution[c/b, {c, b} \[Distributed] BinormalDistribution[{μc, μb}, {σc, σb}, ρ]]]`?

Comment: @J.M. I have not been able to obtain a result (evaluation is has been running for half an hour)

Comment: What version of *Mathematica* are you on? Version 11 quickly yields an answer for the snippet I gave.

Comment: @J.M. Version 10 Student Edition... But if you did get a solution it might just be a question of time.

Comment: Hmm, it also runs quickly in 10.4.1; I do not have earlier point releases of version 10, so someone else might want to look into this.

Comment: @J.M. Thanks. I have 10.1.0.  It stopped running now and gave no output (I mean gave back the input)